# 'to'-infinitive without the verb

Tags: british-english, infinitives, ellipses

I seem to recall reading somewhere that using a *to*-infinitive with the actual verb omitted (because it's clear from context) — as in

> He asked me to go, but I don't want to. (1)

— is fine in American but not in British English. Brits, or so the story went, append *do*:

> He asked me to go, but I don't want to do. (2)

I know that the above is true about American English, my native dialect: we can use (1). My question concerns British English.

Googling finds that the above (that (1) is wrong in British English) is not correct in such generality. For example, `"can't be arsed to if"` has fifteen-odd results, while `"can't be arsed to do if"` has but one, and it's not in the form of (2).

So...

Did I imagine the rule I stated above? Or is it restricted to particular sentences (or verbs or something)? Or is it correct as stated but outdated? Or what?

Comment: This is anecdotal of course, but as a Brit, I would consider "He asked me to go, but I don't want to do." to be incorrect. If such a rule exists, I believe you're misapplying it.

Comment: I find that this different in use of "do" between British and US English is more common with auxiliary verbs, not infinitives: "I didn't take the garbage out, but I (should have/should have done)."

Comment: To infinitive and beyond!

Comment: @Matt Ellen Buzz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find that this different in use of "do" between British and US English is more common with auxiliary verbs, not infinitives: "I didn't take the garbage out, but I (should have/should have done)."  Then again, I'm not British.  I may have interpreted this incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks, wfaulk. Can Brits confirm in comments? (I don't know whom upvotes are from.)

Comment: Both versions sound fine to me.

Comment: In British English, we'd be unlikely to say "garbage" too. :-)

Answer (score 5):

In your examples, (1) is known as **VP ellipsis** and (2) is **VP elision** (although, not correctly formed: it should be 'He asked me to go, but I don't want to do so.'). Both are phenomena found in other languages, but are particularly prevalent in English (both British and American).

As a linguist, I should point out that both forms are 'correct'; correctness is a function of accepted usage, not what some prescriptive text says! However, maybe it's true that (1) is heard more often in the US than (2), which might be more popular in the UK... Anecdotally -- as a native British English speaker -- both are acceptable to me. I would use (1) more naturally and perhaps (2) in a more formal context.

Comment: Thankfully, the following sentence is not true, if it were then slang and ebonics would appear all over this website and in every printed material from instruction forms to text books:  "correctness is a function of accepted usage, not what some prescriptive text says! "    Language needs Prescriptivists as much, if not more than it needs Descriptivists.  Today's level of speech from young to old has deteriorated drastically due to descriptivists embracing everything.  There must be a line drawn in the sand, and we draw it proudly.  haha  Have fun, good people!

Comment: @Taomerline Descriptivism, as you so call it, doesn't preclude grammaticality. There's nothing inherently 'wrong' with slang or AAVE... Open your mind a bit.

Comment: Dear @Xophmeister   Simply put, I prefer that slang and AAVE go back to being the exception and not the rule.  We disagree, and that is fine.  Stay civil!

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion, but let me get this straight: Say a mathematics (or science, or history; it doesn't matter) textbook were published in AAVE which showed an undeniably causal link in significantly (i.e., not due to chance) improving the test scores of the AAVE speaking community (while not at the expense of non-AAVE speakers, who would presumably stick with the English version). You'd be against that?

Comment: As for slang -- which are basically invented/coopted words with a novel meaning -- a certain [Mr. Shakespeare](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/biography/wordsinvented.html) might have something to say about that! Or, let’s say you met Geoffery Chaucer: You probably wouldn’t understand each other, despite claiming to both speak English.